# Yum as root only works if I use the sudo command

Tags: rhel, sudo, root, path

This is for RHEL 7.8...

I support a VM for a customer where another third-party uses the root account to update packages.  When they use yum as root, they receive a timeout, like this (note: this is not package-specific and it is not repo-specific):

```
https://rhui-2.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://rhui-2.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/microsoft-azure-rhel7/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
```

However, I've noticed that when I issue the sudo command, everything works just fine.

To  summarize, **as root**, this command **doesn't work** (It just times out when trying to access any repo, see the above timeout error):

```
yum install -y java-11-openjdk
```

But this command **does work**:

```
sudo yum install -y java-11-openjdk
```

Any ideas what would cause this issue?  Obviously, everything is fine with sudo.  The customer wants them to use the root account, so making them their own account is not an option.  I am really just wondering why you would ever have to run sudo as root to get something to work?  Is this a PATH issue?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

-Adam, RHCE

Comment: You should indicate what is the displayed error when `yum` doesn’t work.

Comment: The displayed "error," is just a timeout response from trying to access any repository, in this specific case, the Microsoft RHUI.  This is the same type of response you would get if you ran yum without sudo on a non-root user, which is why it's really weird to me.

Comment: @adamfink Could the root user have a proxy configuration enabled using environment variables? Then `sudo` runs the command in a minimal environment, bypassing the proxy.

Comment: I agree with Haxiel's comment. To check this (but that's not reliable enough), you could see if using `sudo -i` to force reading of login scripts of a login shell would again make this not work anymore.